# how to change only current component style on hover

Tags: reactjs

I have a requirement where I need to highlight the component on hover

I have two styles defined `baseStyle` and `highlight`

```
<div style={{ background: '#fff' }}>
                    <div
                        onMouseEnter={(e) => setToolStyle({ ...baseStyle, ...highlight })}
                        onMouseLeave={e => setToolStyle(baseStyle)}
                        style={toolStyle}>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMousePointer} style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} />
                    </div>
                    <div
                        onMouseEnter={(e) => setToolStyle({ ...baseStyle, ...highlight })}
                        onMouseLeave={e => setToolStyle(baseStyle)}
                        style={toolStyle}>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMousePointer} style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

***Expected Output:***
on hovering any of the component only that component must be highlighted(i.e just need to add `highlight css class` to it).

but right now all the component is getting highlighted because of `toolStyle` state. can anyone help me on this by giving some logic.

Comment: Show your `setToolStyle` function in the code.

Comment: make it a small component and call it multiple times.

Comment: Can you not use pure CSS? It seems to be a lot more complex doing react way

Comment: @MichałSzymański on css hover is not working. I don't know why. So I came here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

you can create a small component with the highlight effect
and use it component any number of times and from anywhere
(As I said in comments )

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-mclaren-4i8en?file=/src/highlight.js

child.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
const baseStyle = { color: "black", fontSize: 14 };
const highlight = { color: "red" };
export default function Highlight({ text }) {
  const [toolStyle, setToolStyle] = useState(baseStyle);
  return (
    <div
      onMouseEnter={(e) => setToolStyle({ ...baseStyle, ...highlight })}
      onMouseLeave={(e) => setToolStyle(baseStyle)}
      style={toolStyle}
    >
      {text}
    </div>
  );
}
```

parent.js

```
import Highlight from "./highlight";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Highlight text="text 1" />
      <Highlight text="text 2" />
      <Highlight text="text 3" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the best way to implement this with code reusability and
less of code duplication

Comment: I guess This is the pure react way

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  let [hovered, setHovered] = React.useState({ div1: false, div2: false });
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className={hovered.div1 ? 'hovered' : ''}
        onMouseEnter={(e) => setHovered((ps) => ({ ...ps, div1: true }))}
        onMouseLeave={(e) => setHovered((ps) => ({ ...ps, div1: false }))}
      >
        Hello
      </div>
      <div
        className={hovered.div2 ? 'hovered' : ''}
        onMouseEnter={(e) => setHovered((ps) => ({ ...ps, div2: true }))}
        onMouseLeave={(e) => setHovered((ps) => ({ ...ps, div2: false }))}
      >
        Hello
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes that's the problem I'm facing right now. I don't want to create separate state as I'm getting all componets from server, I don't know how many are there. Is it possible

Comment: Hey Thank you, I can loop the state also, That's the hack I'm expecting. Thank you

Comment: you are duplicating the same code here. the best method is to create a child component and use it in parent components

Comment: @sojin I am not duplicating this was for demo OP could generate these `div`s in loop also. It is up to OP to decide if using separate components is more suitable for him/her.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your styles to CSS file and avoid extra complexity:

App.js

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCoffee } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
.wrapper {
  background: #fff;
}

.wrapper > div {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper > div:hover {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```